# Corners cutout custom button background

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am fairly new to UWP but I am familiar with Android programming in XML and Java/Kotlin.
I want to create a button which has its corners cut out and basically looks like this:

[image].

I have created this shape above using `Polygon` XAML element and its `Points` attribute as following:
`<Polygon Points="10,0,100,0,110,10,110,50,100,60,10,60,0,50,0,10" />`.
Can I use this `Polygon` or can I achieve this another way?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use this Polygon

Sure, UWP contains [`Polygon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Polygon) class, and you could use it directly. And [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/shapes#polygon) is sample tutorial that you could refer.

And if you want to make Polygon as content for Button, you could refer the following code

```
<Button Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible">
    <Button.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPressed" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
    </Button.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Polygon Fill="Red" Points="10,0,100,0,110,10,110,50,100,60,10,60,0,50,0,10" />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello Btn" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: That worked partly. Is there a more generic way to do this? This way the background is fixed and does not give feedback to the user like a normal button. When my text gets longer it simply "outgrows" the polygon because it is hardcoded. What I am looking for is a style for buttons who don't have round or edgy corners but the cutout like the polygon and when I hover over it the buttons borders should be in a different color and all that stuff a normal button can do.

Comment: The better way is custom button style and edit button ControlTemplate that contains all button status, please check this  default button [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button#control-style-and-template).